# Django insert data to model with foreign key

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models

I am using django models and am running into issues. I have a couple of models that I am trying to load data to, one with a foreign key to another. I will use two models as an example, but the hope is that I can write the code so that it will generalize to work for models with different names and different field names. The models look as follows:

```
class ProgramInfo(models.Model):
    program_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    ...

class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    program_code = models.ForeignKey('ProgramInfo', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I also have a dictionary called _model_dict with the field names of StudentInfo as the keys and the values being the values I want to put in the model. When I run

```
_model.objects.update_or_create(**_model_dict)
```

It tells me

```
Cannot assign "'ABCD'": "StudentInfo.program_code" must be a "ProgramInfo" instance.
```

Even though that value exists in the ProgramInfo table.
I have no issue inserting data to models without foreign keys using this same method.

As I understand it the value for the key in _model_dict of the foreign key field should not just be the value for a single field, but an object of the model the foreign key links to.
I tried singling out the foreign key fields in order to be able to use model_get with filter and obtain the row from the target model and put that in the _model_dict but I couldn't find out how to obtain the target model given a known ForeignKey field. Because I intend the to generalize I don't want to specify the target model in specific code, but will like to obtain it from the field that I managed to conclude was the foreign key field. I have been googling around for many hours now and can't find the attribute for the target model a of ForeignKey field.

i don't know if it will be useful, but here is the code I used for trying to create a class for the foreign key:

```
                # check for foreign keys
            _model_field_objects = [f for f in _model._meta.get_fields()]
            foreign_key_fields_dict = {}
            for field in _model_field_objects:
                if field.__class__ is ForeignKey:
                    foreign_key_fields_dict[field.name] =  field #here i try to obtain target model of the field
            print("Foreign key fields are: " + str(foreign_key_fields_dict))
            sys.stdout.flush()

            for row in data:
                _model_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(titles, row) if key in _model_field_names}

                # adjust foreign key to their class
                for key in _model_dict:
                    filter_arguments = {}
                    if key in foreign_key_fields_dict:
                        filter_arguments[key] = _model_dict[key]
                        _model_dict[key] = foreign_key_fields_dict[key].objects.filter(**filter_arguments)

                # insert to table
                _model.objects.update_or_create(**_model_dict)
```

I am probably way over complicating this. If there is a simple way Django provides for adding to a model with foreign keys given the known value for the foreign key field (and not the full object for the model it points to) I would be glad to learn of it.
Thanks in advance for any help available!

Comment: No reason to have program_code in both models. If one model is a foreign key of the other, you can access the value from either instance of those objects.

Comment: Thats just how it was easy for me to name it, in StudentInfo it could have been called "program", and the program has a code and other attributes in programInfo. Does it having the same name make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

because `program_code` is the primarykey in the `ProgramInfo` model, you can set or get using the value of that field:

for example, lets say you have a `ProgramInfo` instance with a primarykey that its value is 'abcd', you can create a StudentInfo using that like this:

```
StudentInfo.objects.create(program_code_id='abcd', ..... other fields ....)
```

because `program_code_id` is what that really is stored in the StudentInfo database.

Comment: I solved it in a different convoluted way, and I am too scared to change it to what you said. I knew that django adds a _id suffix but didn't know that's what it meant. I am sorry but I don't want to accept an answer I haven't tried, but thanks for the input! hopefully someone else tries it and can upvote if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in an non-elegant way that works for me. Other answers given might be better, but I am too scared to change my code for now as it seems to be working. Here is what I did in case it can help anyone else:
Using:
`from pprint import pprint
pprint(vars(myobject))`
I managed to find out that the `ForeignKey` type object has an attribute `ForeignKey.related_model`. Once I had the model I could use it as follows to obtain the row in the model that is being pointed to:

```
field.related_model.objects.get(pk=_model_dict[key])
```

where `field` is the field in the model that I am trying to insert data into. The result from that could be put into the _model_dict dictionary containing all the other values for fields for the model I am inserting data into, so using the following worked for inserting the data:

```
_model.objects.update_or_create(**_model_dict)
```

NOTE:
The update_or_create would sometimes crash saying there was a problem with uniqueness, which I thought was the "update_or" part was suppose to resolve. In any case adding a try/except around it solved that problem for me - though I know its a hack..